# Is there a way in PyQGIS to bypass the identify functionnality of QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem creation?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, proj

While implementing a geodetic buffering system similar to [Approximating Geodesic Buffers with PyQGIS](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/05/geodesic-buffers-in-qgis/) I noticed the buffering is extremely slow.

```py
with Timer.context(msg="buffered_geom_function"):
    geometry = QgsGeometry(geometry)

    crs_wgs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")
    crs_transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(self.crs, crs_wgs, QgsProject.instance())
    
    with Timer.context(msg="transforms"):
        if self.crs != crs_wgs:
            geometry.transform(crs_transform)
            
    with Timer.context(msg="centroid"):
        centroid = geometry.centroid()
        x = centroid.asPoint().x()
        y = centroid.asPoint().y()
        
    with Timer.context(msg="crs_proj_string_formatting"):
        proj_string = self.PROJ_STR.format(y, x)

    with Timer.context(msg="QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem_instantiation"):
        dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
        dest_crs.createFromProj(proj_string)

    with Timer.context(msg="QgsCoordinateTransform_instantiation"):
        xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crs_wgs, dest_crs, QgsCoordinateTransformContext())
        
    with Timer.context(msg="transforms"):
        geometry.transform(xform)
        
    with Timer.context(msg="buffer"):
        buffer = geometry.buffer(distance, segments)
        
    with Timer.context(msg="transforms"):
        buffer.transform(xform, QgsCoordinateTransform.ReverseTransform)
        
    with Timer.context(msg="transforms"):
        if self.crs != crs_wgs:
            buffer.transform(crs_transform, QgsCoordinateTransform.ReverseTransform)
```

Profiling my function gave me this

```
- QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem_instantiation -> 11.253s (calls: 579, - average time : 19.436ms)
- QgsCoordinateTransform_instantiation -> 2.475s (calls: 579, average - time : 4.275ms)
- transforms -> 63.259ms (calls: 2316, average time : 27µs)
- buffer -> 43.522ms (calls: 579, average time : 75µs)
- centroid -> 13.006ms (calls: 579, average time : 22µs)
- crs_proj_string_formatting -> 1.998ms (calls: 579, average time : 3µs)
TOTAL: buffered_geom_function() -> 13.885s (calls: 579, average time : 23.981ms)
```

As you can see 80% of the processing time is spent instantiating `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` objects.

I wonder why it takes so much time.
I am aware it tries to check for known/registered CRS in cache/database when creating a CRS from a PROJ string. I am guessing it is the actual process of matching for a known CRS that takes a long time (or maybe not?).

I mean even in the [API documentation of the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.createFromProj`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#a5fa4fae2ddfabb3f570405d375edcd74) there is on the C++ side an `identify` boolean parameter that allows bypassing the CRS matching and directly generating a new CRS from the PROJ string, which is sadly not available on the Python API.

So I was wondering if anyone knows of a faster way of creating custom QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem objects from PROJ strings?

**EDIT**:
@CodeBard suggestion gives an easy ~25% faster runtime without modifying the rest of the code.

```
- QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem_instantiation -> 7.735s (calls: 579, average time : 13.360ms)
- QgsCoordinateTransform_instantiation -> 2.352s (calls: 579, average time : 4.063ms)
- transforms -> 61.613ms (calls: 2316, average time : 27µs)
- buffer -> 51.469ms (calls: 579, average time : 89µs)
- centroid -> 5.979ms (calls: 579, average time : 10µs)
- crs_proj_string_formatting -> 3.710ms (calls: 579, average time : 6µs)
TOTAL: buffered_geom_function -> 10.250s (calls: 579, average time : 17.704ms)
```

`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` and `QgsCoordinateTransform` objects remain still quite computationally expensive.

Comment: And what happens in `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem_instantiation`? Where to see the code?

Comment: @VsevolodTsukanov Updated, but like I said it is simply the instantiation using `createFromProj`

Comment: And there, for each feature, its own projection is created from the proj line? Does each feature need its own projection?

Comment: If you have features over a wide area of the world or even a country for example then yes definitely. And I do want the accuracy that doing individual projections gives me.

Comment: The first link you gave has these two lines of code: `proj_string = 'PROJ4:+proj=aeqd +ellps=WGS84 +lat_0={} +lon_0={} +x_0=0 +y_0=0'.format(y, x)`
       `dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(proj_string)` Maybe they will work faster, have you tried it?

Comment: No, it's basically identical to what I do, except the way I do it doesn't have to figure out if it is a PROJ string and not a WKT or an EPSG identifier. so at most, my way is as fast or faster than the linked code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a full [`pyproj`](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) solution which allowed me to make the function **~x34 (or ~97%)** faster. To achieve this, I use the [`Proj`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/proj.html#proj) class of the `pyproj` library.

```
from pyproj.proj import Proj
from pyproj.enums import TransformDirection
...
...
type_geom = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(geometry.wkbType()).lower()
if "multi" in type_geom:
    if not geometry.convertToSingleType():
        raise TypeError("Geometry shouldn't be multi type")
if "point" in type_geom:
    points = [tuple(geometry.asPoint())]
    build_geom = lambda list_points: QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(*next(list_points)))
elif "linestring" in type_geom:
    points = [tuple(pt) for pt in geometry.asPolyline()]
    build_geom = lambda list_points: QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(*pt) for pt in list_points])
elif "polygon" in type_geom:
    points = [tuple(pt) for pt in geometry.asPolygon()[0]]
    build_geom = lambda list_points: QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[QgsPointXY(*pt) for pt in list_points]])
else:
    raise TypeError(f"Geometry should be a point, linestring or polygon; not {type_geom}")

# Input CRS to WGS CRS
if self.crs != self.crs_wgs:
    points_wgs = list(self.proj_source.itransform(points, direction=TransformDirection.INVERSE))
else:
    points_wgs = points

# Centroid
points_wgs_x, points_wgs_y = zip(*points_wgs)
x = sum(points_wgs_x)/len(points_wgs_x)
y = sum(points_wgs_y)/len(points_wgs_y)

# WGS CRS to locally projected CRS
proj_string = self.PROJ_STR.format(y, x)
proj_dest = Proj(proj_string)
points_projected = proj_dest.itransform(points_wgs)

# Buffering
geometry = build_geom(points_projected)
buffer = geometry.buffer(distance, segments)
points_projected = [tuple(pt) for pt in buffer.asPolygon()[0]]

# locally projected CRS to WGS CRS
points_wgs = proj_dest.itransform(points_projected, direction=TransformDirection.INVERSE)

# WGS CRS to input CRS
if self.crs != self.crs_wgs:
    points = self.proj_source.itransform(points_wgs)
else:
    points = points_wgs

# Rebuild of the QgsGeometry from points
buffer = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[QgsPointXY(*pt) for pt in points]])
```

```py
from pyproj.proj import Proj
from pyproj.enums import TransformDirection
...
...
with Timer.context(msg="buffered_geom_function"):
    type_geom = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(geometry.wkbType()).lower()
    if "multi" in type_geom:
        if not geometry.convertToSingleType():
            raise TypeError("Geometry shouldn't be multi type")
    if "point" in type_geom:
        points = [tuple(geometry.asPoint())]
        build_geom = lambda list_points: QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(*next(list_points)))
    elif "linestring" in type_geom:
        points = [tuple(pt) for pt in geometry.asPolyline()]
        build_geom = lambda list_points: QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(*pt) for pt in list_points])
    elif "polygon" in type_geom:
        points = [tuple(pt) for pt in geometry.asPolygon()[0]]
        build_geom = lambda list_points: QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[QgsPointXY(*pt) for pt in list_points]])
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"Geometry should be a point, linestring or polygon; not {type_geom}")

    with Timer.context(msg="transforms"):
        if self.crs != self.crs_wgs:
            points_wgs = list(self.proj_source.itransform(points, direction=TransformDirection.INVERSE))
        else:
            points_wgs = points

    with Timer.context(msg="centroid"):
        points_wgs_x, points_wgs_y = zip(*points_wgs)
        x = sum(points_wgs_x)/len(points_wgs_x)
        y = sum(points_wgs_y)/len(points_wgs_y)

    with Timer.context(msg="crs_proj_string_formatting"):
        proj_string = self.PROJ_STR.format(y, x)

    with Timer.context(msg="QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem_instantiation"):
        proj_dest = Proj(proj_string)

    with Timer.context(msg="transforms"):
        points_projected = proj_dest.itransform(points_wgs)

    with Timer.context(msg="buffer"):
        geometry = build_geom(points_projected)
        buffer = geometry.buffer(distance, segments)
        points_projected = [tuple(pt) for pt in buffer.asPolygon()[0]]

    with Timer.context(msg="transforms"):
        points_wgs = proj_dest.itransform(points_projected, direction=TransformDirection.INVERSE)

    with Timer.context(msg="transforms"):
        if self.crs != self.crs_wgs:
            points = self.proj_source.itransform(points_wgs)
        else:
            points = points_wgs

    buffer = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[QgsPointXY(*pt) for pt in points]])
```

Profiling:

```
- QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem_instantiation -> 220.656ms (calls: 579, average time : 381µs)
- transforms -> 80.139ms (calls: 2316, average time : 35µs)
- buffer -> 73.916ms (calls: 579, average time : 128µs)
- crs_proj_string_formatting -> 2.684ms (calls: 579, average time : 5µs)
- centroid -> 2ms (calls: 579, average time : 3µs)
TOTAL: buffered_geom_function -> 405.840ms (calls: 579, average time : 701µs)
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I could think of would be to skip the comparison with the user defined CRS by setting the `pkgDataPath` to an invalid directory.
This will prevent QGIS from finding the `crs.db` sqlite file and it won't emit any SQL statement to read from the database. [This statement](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/proj/qgscoordinatereferencesystem.cpp#L1108) should evaluate to true if the database was not found and therefore return early.

This decreases the execution time to approx. 1ms instead of 1.5ms on my setup where there is not a single user defined CRS stored. I guess depending on the content of your spatial reference database it may prove even more effective, since the SQL query and results will be much larger if there are more user CRS stored.

```
with catchtime('default') as t:
    proj_string = '+proj=aeqd +ellps=WGS84 +lat_0=1 +lon_0=3 +x_0=0 +y_0=0'
    dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
    dest_crs.createFromProj(proj_string)

with catchtime('modify package path') as t:
    data_path = QgsApplication.pkgDataPath()
    QgsApplication.setPkgDataPath('')
    proj_string = '+proj=aeqd +ellps=WGS84 +lat_0=1 +lon_0=2 +x_0=0 +y_0=0'
    dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
    dest_crs.createFromProj(proj_string)
    QgsApplication.setPkgDataPath(data_path)

# outputs
default Time: 1.563 ms
modify package path Time: 1.072 ms
```

I also wonder why the `identify` parameter is deliberately excluded from pyqgis bindings...

Comment: So fast, maybe it's because the projection is being read from the cache? If you add the line `dest_crs.invalidateCache()` after the code, what will be the execution time of the next iteration?

Comment: @VsevolodTsukanov I put two different proj_strings on purpose so that it won't read from cache :) I can also switch the order of those two blocks, then the first one is faster. If it does read from cache (e.g. if I ran the script two times), then execution time is only a fraction of a millisecond for both blocks

Comment: @CodeBard It's definitely a good full PyQGIS solution. however still kinda slow. I will post what I ended up doing soon.